# NodeJS wait until mySQL query insert multiple values is completed

Tags: mysql, node.js

I'm trying to insert data in a loop, but it did not wait until the insert was complete.

My code looks as follows:

```
con.query('INSERT INTO pair_report_detail (studentID1, studentID2, result1, result2) 
VALUES  (\''+studentID[i]+'\', \''+studentID[j]+'\', 
'+result1.toFixed(2)+', '+result2.toFixed(2)+')', function(err, result) {
          if (err) throw err;
          
          var pair_report_detailID = result.insertId;
          var tokenMatchMarks = 0;
          var matchNo = 0;

          console.log(functions[i].length);
          console.log(functions[j].length);


          var sizeFile1 = functions[i].length;
          for(var z = 0; z < 20; z++)
          {
            if(z == tokenMatch1[tokenMatchMarks])
            {
              matchNo++;
              con.query('INSERT INTO functions (studentID, reportID , content, matchno) 
 VALUES  (\''+studentID[i]+'\', '+pair_report_detailID+', \''+functions[i][z]+'\', '+matchNo+')', function(err, result) {
                if (err) throw err;

                tokenMatchMarks++;
                console.log("Insert funtions");
              }); 
            }else
            {
              con.query('INSERT INTO functions (studentID, reportID , content) VALUES  (\''+studentID[i]+'\', '+pair_report_detailID+', \''+functions[i][z]+'\')', function(err, result) {
                if (err) throw err;
                console.log("Insert funtions");

              }); 
            }
          }
          });
```

I do understand that NodeJS works async and doesn't wait for any function to be completed. But there must be a way this is possible. What am I doing wrong, or what do I misunderstand?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Take a look at [MySQL 2 Package](https://www.npmjs.com/package/mysql2)

The reason is in your answer. `NodeJS` is `async`, hence, it does not wait for the loop to complete.

`mysql2` package contains mysql with promises so it will greatly assist you achieve your goal. especially using `async` and `await`

Also: use `let` instead of `var` for loops

Answer (score 0):

Also you can use recursion.

Some recommendations:

- Use `?`-placeholder when you execute queries to avoid sql-injection
- Use transaction: if one of 20 queries will fall then db will have wrong data. You can avoid it by transaction: `begin; <insert pair_report_detail>; <20 times: insert functions>; commit;` and do `rollback;` on any error.

I don't know what do you need exactly so below a hypotetical code :)

```
let query1 = 'insert into pair_report_detail (studentID1, studentID2, result1, result2) values (?, ?, ?, ?)';
let query2 = 'insert into functions (studentID, reportID , content, matchno) values (?, ?, ?, ?)';

con.query(query1, [studentID[i], studentID[j], result1.toFixed(2), result2.toFixed(2)], function (err, results) {
    if (err)
        throw err;

    let id = result.insertId;
    let tokenMatchMarks = 0;
    let matchNo = 0;  

    function insert (idx) {
        if (idx == 20)
            return console.log('DONE!');

        let isMatch = tokenMatch1[tokenMatchMarks]; 
        if (isMatch)
            tokenMatchMarks++;

        con.query(query2, [studentID[i], id, functions[i][idx], isMatch ? matchNo : null], function (err, res) {
            if (err)
                throw err;

            insert (idx + 1);   
        })  
    }

    insert (0);
});
```